# Webpack 4 / SCSS: extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin and style-loader as fallback

Tags: webpack, sass, slick.js

I use extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin for hot reloading and I want to include a fallback (style-loader) to my scss|css loader.

Why: I get the following error while loading the slick slider plugin:

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/vendor/slick-theme.scss
va_dev_1  | Module build failed (from ./node_modules/extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin/dist/loader.js):
va_dev_1  | ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
va_dev_1  | You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

(slick-theme.scss is referencing to fonts and images)
How can I add the style-loader as a fallback? (Line 78 - 87 in the config). I found some solutions with style-loader as fallback, but it's not working with ExtractCssChunks.loader (line 79) in my case.

Webpack config:
https://gist.github.com/cgpro/7103cb6f71fec845d7c42c82acc75d38

slick-theme.scss:
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick-theme.scss

(va_dev_1 is the docker container name, btw)

Comment: show how you import that ExtractCssChunksLoader, i suspect it is mini-css-extract-plugin

Comment: Could you also include the error message you get?

Comment: And what can of behavior do you mean by "fallback"?

Comment: The others are right, you should edit your question and give more detailed information about your problem. Provide full webpack config and error messages. Anyway, you may use something like ’isHot ? style-loader : ExtractCssChunk.loader’ (Just define the variable first.)

Comment: Sorry, updated my question! Thanks for your response! :-)

Comment: Any suggestions? *push*